# Вопрос с чатом на python и socket

Tags: python-3.x, сокет, chat

Когда пользователь подключается к чату - он отправляет на сервер свой *username* и свой *ip*. Далее для него идет выбор куда писать:

1. Direct
2. Group
3. Global chat

И вот в чем проблема, если с *Direct* все ясно, то как можно реализовать *Group* и *Global chat*? 
Вот что отправляет клиент на сервер:

```
'from_user': username,
'code': 'global',
'to_user': to_user,
'text': text,
'ip': ip, # socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
'port': 750
```

и сервер принимает пакет как `message` и смотрит, есть ли пользователь в `clients {}`, если нет - он добавляет его через `clients[message['from_user']] = message['ip']`.

И если клиент хочет написать в глобальный чат, то как можно это все реализовать? 
Может что-то нужно добавить или убрать? 
Реально ли сделать группой чат примерно как код ниже:

```
'from_user': username,
'code': 'global',

'to_user': [user1, user2, user3],

'text': text,
'ip': ip, # socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
'port': 750
```

я не очень разбираюсь в этом, поэтому буду рад услышать критику :)

upd: про

> как код ниже

если в поле `to_user` добавить массив с никами. 
Т.е если *user1* хочет написать *user2*, *user3* и *user4*, то на сервер отправляется пакет и в поле указывается `to_user` и флажком `group: True`  . Получается сервер может отправлять другим участникам как

```
i = 0
for i > len(message['to_user']:
   socket.sendto(message, (message['to_user'][i], 750))
```

Верно? и если есть ошибка - как устранить

Comment: Не увидел никакого кода...

Comment: кода чего? могу добавить

Comment: `Реально ли сделать группой чат примерно как код ниже:` и нет кода.

Comment: обновил и уточнил